# Apache 2.4.10 hangs AH00485: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: apache, sparc

Apache server will stay up for random amount of time, usually days, but eventually enters a hung state. When hung the CPU load gradually spikes on the machine and new web server requests are unresponsive.

Error logs typically contain lots of these:

> Wed Jan 28 16:06:58.667188 2015] [mpm_event:error] [pid 25336:tid 1] AH00485: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

Environment:

LDOM (VM) SunOS myhostname 5.10 Generic_118833-36 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200

http Conf:

```
StartServers                8
MinSpareServers             Not set
MaxSpareServers             Not set
ServerLimit                 256
MaxRequestWorkers           100
MaxConnectionsPerChild      1000
KeepAlive                   On
TimeOut                     3000
MaxKeepAliveRequests        50
KeepAliveTimeout            2
```

Current non-hung Score Board:

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
Server MPM: event
Server Built: Oct 30 2014 16:29:03

Current Time: Wednesday, 28-Jan-2015 10:59:39 PST
Restart Time: Wednesday, 28-Jan-2015 09:49:21 PST
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 1 hour 10 minutes 17 seconds
Server load: 0.60 0.46 0.41
Total accesses: 1134 - Total Traffic: 2.2 GB
CPU Usage: u9.07 s16.94 cu609.51 cs69.31 - 16.7% CPU load
.269 requests/sec - 0.5 MB/second - 2.0 MB/request
1 requests currently being processed, 99 idle workers

PID Connections     Threads Async connections
total   accepting   busy    idle    writing keep-alive  closing
25337   0   yes 1   24  0   0   0
25338   1   yes 0   25  1   0   0
25339   1   yes 0   25  0   0   1
25340   1   yes 0   25  0   0   1
Sum 3       1   99  1   0   2
```

Any thoughts on http conf tuning, OS patches, apache bug fixes appreciated.

Yes I have seen the open ASF bugzilla for the same error message.

This is a production server, so you can imagine, having it go down at random times (usually when I am asleep) is not fun!